# vim pymode - sort lint errors and warnings by significance

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I was wondering if there is any way to have errors always appear before PEP-8 warnings in the lint output?

Either of re-ordering the output or having PEP-8 and other style warnings only reported if there are no errors would work for my needs.